# Getting posted data from ajax to flask server and displaying template

Tags: javascript, python, flask

**Edit**
I don't think my question qualifies a duplicate (at not obvious to a lay user like me). Either way let me clarify what I need, and my present kludgy solution.

1. A user event (ctrl v) sends data to the server using a 'POST' method. The only reason I am using ajax is to get pasted images from the clipboard.
2. On the server a flask/python function reads the data, and eventually displays the results in the form render_template('index.html',results=func(request.form))

Surely this can't be that tricky. From the comments below I came up with a makedo solution. ajax posts to server, python saves data to a file, returns the `filename` to ajax. The `done` function in ajax is modified to redirect to a url containing the filename.

```
done(function(filename) {
        window.location.href = "/scan/"+filename;
        });
```

And *finally* I have a route for

```
@app.route('/scan/<filename>',methods=['POST']) 
def somefunc(filename):
    #stuff
    return render_template("index.html",results=...)
```

I have no idea whether this is a good way to do this or even safe.

#### Original post

In this simple example, a script listens for a 'paste' (ctrl+v) event, and then routes it to a flask/python function. But for some reason the last render_template call is never executed.

**html & javascript**

```
<body>
Press Ctrl+V (page must be focused)
<br /><br />
{%if msg %}
    {{ msg }}
{% endif %}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
//Listen for a Ctr+V event
document.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {send_data(e);},false);

send_data = function (e) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('data', "Mytest");
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/pastetest',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
    }).done(function() {
       console.log('sent to server');
        });
    e.preventDefault();
};
</script>
</body>
```

**Flask/python**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("yo")
    return render_template('paste4.html',msg="Waiting")

@app.route('/pastetest',methods=['POST']) 
def image_upload():
    print("On the server")
    print(request.form)
    return render_template('paste4.html',msg="All Done") #<-- Doesn't execute??
```

The output on the terminal confirms that everything went smoothly with the 'POST'.

```
 * Serving Flask app "pasteapp"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
yo
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2017 21:25:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
On the server
ImmutableMultiDict([('data', 'Mytest')])
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2017 21:25:42] "POST /pastetest HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But the last 'All Done' is never displayed on the page. I just can't understand what's going here.

Comment: It is being executed and returned, but your Ajax function is ignoring it.

Comment: Could you explain more? I am pretty clueless about Ajax and javascript. I am just using it to send data (image actually) from the clipboard. Once it gets to the server, I want to process and display the results using python... and listen for the next 'paste' event

Comment: The whole point of Ajax is that it makes a request without reloading the page. So if you want to change what's on your page, you need to do it in the `done` function.

Comment: Could you post an example? All I need is for the server to take over after receiving the data. If there's a simpler way without jquery, that's fine too.